# Problem declaring in if statement and the use it in functions

Tags: javascript

My problem lies in defining a variable inside an if statement and using it in a function like:

Why is this not working? Are there any workarounds to the issue?My goal is to use as little variables as possible

```
let level

function findLevel(){
   if (document.title.indexOf("PageTitle") != -1) {
      level = 1
   }else{
      level = 2
   }
}

if (level == 1) {
  var x = 1
  //more variables like x that are going to be used in more than one functions..
}else{
 var y = 2
//more variables like y that are going to be used in more than one functions..
}

function functionName() {
  console.log(level)    // prints 1
  console.log(x)        // prints undefined
  // ...some Work...
}

function functionName2(){
 //also need x or y
}

//more functions like this
window.onload =function(){ 
 findLevel(); functionName();
}
```

My goal is to declare as minimum as possible variables I can

Comment: They are undefined because they are being used in the wrong [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). You can declare the variables [globally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_variable), or pass them as [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) to the functions that need them

Comment: `x` is undefined because initially `level` is undefined as well. So `x` is never assigned a value.

Comment: don' use `var` anymore. it's dangerously outdated. learn how to use `const` and `let` and enjoy

Comment: level is not undefined

Comment: I could put them globaly but if level 2, y will never be used.Can I make something like I posted above so variables like x be defined only if level == 1 and and y only if level == 2.

Comment: `level` does start off `undefined`. `let level` isn't assigning a value so it's `undefined`

Comment: _"My goal is to declare as minimum as possible variables I can"_: maybe use an object.

Comment: it is assigned in find level

Comment: Understand that `level = 1` happens *after* `if (level == 1)`!

Comment: @Omnni, yes but `findLevel` runs after the if/else. So `var y = 2` is executed and `x` stays `undefined`.

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on the [order of execution](https://medium.com/@marcellamaki/a-brief-overview-of-order-of-execution-in-javascript-e28744aa9479) of JavaScript

Answer (score -5):

The variables declared in the if statement, x and y, are in that scope, which means they are not accessible from the global or another scope. Like you did with level, declare x and y at the beginning as such:

```
let level, x, y;
```

This way, if level is NOT 1, x will be declared, and if it IS 1, then y will be declared.

Comment: `var` is *not* block scoped.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: It still acts weird when used inside functions/loops/if statements and such. Its outdated and should not be used in ECMA6 enviornments